# jmeter invoking other thread group variable in controller

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter

Have 2 Jmeter threadgroups in a testplan.

```
Threadgroup 1
  Java sampler 1 
         - produce some messages
     Constant timer delay with 1000ms.

Threadgroup 2
  Java sampler 2 
        - Message will have 2 variables like "${var1} is going for walk in ${var2} ground"
     Constant timer delay with 60000ms.
```

Each threadgroup will have 10 threads running for 30 mins.

But Threadgroup 1 threads willproduce meesage for every second. Threadgroup2 threads will produce messages for every minute based on delay in timer.

Both threadgroups are running parellaly

This far I am able to get it worked.

But I have one portion which i am not sure how to implement that.  Var2 in second threadgroup2 java sampler is dynamically generated one. I need to control my threadgroup 1 sampler based on this var2 value of the same threadnumber.

```
i.e If thread1 of second threadgroup2 var2 has value "abc", then thread1 in threadgroup2 should not execute. Untill same threadnumber in second threadgroup , changes the value. Only that particular thread number should get controlled.

Other threads should continue to execute. I tried to place while controller with var2 == "abc" & if controller . But did not see any change.
```

Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fastest and the easiest solution would be using [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin which is basically a [FIFO queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) so you will be able to pause `Java sampler 1` execution until your condition is met, see [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx)  Test Plan for reference.

You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin in 2 ways:

1. Manually downloading [jpgc-fifo](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-fifo) bundle and placing the content of the archive to "lib" and "lib/ext" folders of your JMeter installation
2. Install it automatically using the [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager), look for `Inter-Thread Communication` at the "Available Plugins" tab. This way you will also be notified about this and other plugins updates

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager Inter Thread Communication]