# JMeter WebSockets Publish/Subscribe - scripting aschronous responses

Tags: websocket, jmeter, stomp

We have built a publish/subscribe model into our application via WebSockets so users can receive "dynamic updates" when data changes.  I'm now looking to load test this using JMeter.

Is there a way to configure a JMeter test to react to receipt of a WebSocket "published" message and then run further samplers i.e. make further web requests?

I have looked at plugin samples, but they appear focused on request/reply model (e.g. https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers) rather than publish/subscribe.

**Edit:**

I have progressed a solution for this using the WebSocketSampler - an Example JMX file can be found [on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/infracentric/jmeter-scripts/src/7a519916cc3db17bba46a7ae36cf3e15161ee344/WebSocketSTOMPExample.jmx?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) which uses STOMP over WebSockets and includes Connect, Subscribe, Handle Publish Message and Initiate JMeter Samplers from that.

Comment: Try ZebraTester. It supports websockets

Comment: @Vinit thanks - I'll check that out - JMeter supports WebSockets (via plugins) if you know that ZebraTest supports async (callback) style usage that would help.  As we've already invested time etc in JMeter I'm keen to see if I can make that work first.

Comment: If you are talking about MQTT over web-sockets, that will be available in the upcoming version of ZebraTester

Comment: We're actually using STOMP over WebSockets

Comment: ahh that's not supported or on the roadmap at the moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a misunderstanding that the https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/overview plugin only supports request-response model conversations.

Since version 0.7, the plugin offers "single read" and "single write" samplers. Of course, it depends on your exact protocol, but the idea is that you could use a "single write" sampler to send a WebSocket message that simulates creating the subscription and then have a (standard JMeter) While loop in combination with the "single read" samplers, to read any number of messages that are being published.

If this does not satisfy your needs, let me know and i'll see what i can do for you (i'm the author of this plugin).

Comment: I'd missed that - I'll take a closer look.

Comment: As per Edit on question - I have progressed using WebSocketSamplers with inclusion of initiating JMeter Samplers on message receipt so accepting this as answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the system with STOMP. So the clients executed the HTTP messages and they got the actual state via asynchronous WebSockets with this subscribe model. To emulate this behaviour I wrote a class which via JMeterContext variable could exchange data with Jmeter threads (import part you can find by yourself import org.springframework.*):

```
public class StompWebSocketLoadTestClient {

public static JMeterContext ctx;
public static StompSession session;

public static void start(JMeterContext ctx, String wsURL, String SESSION) throws InterruptedException {
    WebSocketClient transport = new StandardWebSocketClient();

    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(transport);
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
    stompClient.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    stompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(new long[]{10000, 10000});
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new ByteArrayMessageConverter());
    StompSessionHandler handler = new MySessionHandler(ctx);
    WebSocketHttpHeaders handshakeHeaders = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();
    handshakeHeaders.add("Cookie", "SESSION=" + SESSION);
    stompClient.connect(wsURL, handshakeHeaders, handler);
    sleep(1000);
}
```

The messages were handled in this class:

```
private static class MySessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter implements TestStateListener {

    private String Login = "";
    private final JMeterContext ctx_;

    private MySessionHandler(JMeterContext ctx) {
        this.ctx_ = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        session.setAutoReceipt(true);
        this.Login = ctx_.getVariables().get("LOGIN");
        //System.out.println("CONNECTED:" + connectedHeaders.getSession() + ":" + session.getSessionId() + ":" + Login);
        //System.out.println(session.isConnected());
        **//HERE SUBSCRIBTION:**
        session.subscribe("/user/notification", new StompFrameHandler() {

            @Override
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                //System.out.println("getPayloadType:");
                Iterator it = headers.keySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String header = it.next().toString();

                    //System.out.println(header + ":" + headers.get(header));
                }
                //System.out.println("=================");
                return byte[].class;
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                //System.out.println("recievedMessage");
                NotificationList nlist = null;
                try {
                    nlist = NotificationList.parseFrom((byte[]) payload);

                    JMeterVariables vars = ctx_.getVariables();
                    Iterator it = nlist.getNotificationList().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Notification n = (Notification) it.next();
                        String className = n.getType();
                        //System.out.println("CLASS NAME:" + className);

                        if (className.contains("response.Resource")) {
                            ///After getting some message you can work with jmeter variables:
                            vars.putObject("var1", var1);
                            vars.put("var2",String.valueOf(var2));
                        }
                        //Here is "sending" variables back to Jmeter thread context so you can use the data during the test 
                        ctx_.setVariables(vars);
                        n = null;

                    }
                } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(StompWebSocketLoadTestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } 
            }

        });
    }
```

In Jmeter testplan, after Login stage I just added a Beanshell sampler with login/password and session strings and **Jmeter thread context**:

```
import jmeterstopm.StompWebSocketLoadTestClient;
StompWebSocketLoadTestClient ssltc = new StompWebSocketLoadTestClient();
String SERVER_NAME = vars.get("SERVER_NAME");
String SESSION = vars.get("SESSION");
String ws_pref = vars.get("ws_pref");
ssltc.start(ctx,ws_pref+"://"+SERVER_NAME+"/endpoint/notification-    ws/websocket",SESSION);
```

Further is possible to use all incoming via Websockets data with simple **vars** variable:

```
Object var1= (Object) vars.getObject("var1");
```

Comment: that looks very interesting - we are also using STOMP so potentially a good fit.  I see the callback via "handler" - and in there, while I see setting JMeter variables, the bit I'm struggling with is how this triggers further activity - i.e. how to inject further samples in the test - for us this is mainly refreshData from API via HTTP.  Would this require a LoopControl with (say) connect and send initial page request on first time round and if data variable set (i.e. message received) issue a refresh?

Comment: Did not fully get your question, but after you established the connection with this example the any data which will come to this sunscribed channel will be available to use in any jmeter sampler via vars.

Comment: Ok thanks I get the gist - My question was really about JMeter control structures to handle multiple publish responses, but think I can work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, JMeter is not suited well for async type of interaction with system under test.

Though (virtually) everything is possible with Scripting components (post processors, timers, assertions, perhaps samplers, seems to look most useful in your case) and JMeter Logic Controllers.

Like, you may line up your "further samplers", covered in If blocks, analyze the "receipt of a WebSocket published message" and set the flag variables/other parameters for If blocks.

And you may even sync threads, if you need it, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42395137/5828464).

But tell you what - that pretty much looks like a lot of handwritten stuff to be done.

So it make sense to consider the whole custom handwritten test harness too.

Comment: thanks - I was thinking along the same lines (hadn't dug into the specifics) - was just hoping I'd missed something.  I'll have a look at the "Inter-thread" option you link.